# $ (\varphi\circ A)^*$ for convex $\varphi$ and linear continuous $A$

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm reading the paper *"The relevance of convex analysis in the study of monotonicity"* by *Jean-Paul Penot*. (A really nice paper!) There is one *"classical result of convex analysis"* being used:

For Banach spaces $X, Y$, a linear and continuous map $A:X\rightarrow Y$  and $\varphi:Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup \{ + \infty \} $ convex, proper and lower-semicontinuous it holds

$$ (\varphi\circ A)^* = \min \{ \varphi ^* (y^*) : A^* (y^*) = x^* \} $$

if $\mathbb{R}_+(\rm{dom}\ \varphi - \rm{Im}(A))=Y$ (where "min" means that the infimum is attained when it is finite).

Can someone give a proof or provide a good reference? (I am sure that there are generalizations but this level of generality is totally sufficient for me.)

Comment: You may look [here](http://archive.control.lth.se/media/Education/DoctorateProgram/2015/LargeScaleConvexOptimization/Lectures/conj_fcn.pdf), pp. 20-22. Anopther source is [here](https://books.google.se/books?id=hIYKBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA224#v=onepage&q&f=false), the last lemma on the page.

Comment: That look good. (I need to check that the assumption here imply the assumptions in the references you gave.) Thank you very much!